# Networking issues after XEN guest migration

Tags: centos, networking, xen

Yesterday, after mirgation of my CentOS 5.3 VPS from ISP to my own local XEN, I was a little bit complicated: after changing all network settings inside:

```
 /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0
```

(the only virtual eth device on the system)

And, when system boots, nothing was changed (old IP, gateway, etc again). Where old CentOS can store those settings?

just "ifconfig eth0 XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX" works, but only to first reboot/shutdown/servicerestart.

Comment: All values changed inside:

    /etc/sysconfig/networking/profiles/default/ifcfg-eth0
    /etc/sysconfig/networking/devices/ifcfg-eth0

Still the same.